# Get contacts by MIME type in Android

Tags: android

I want to get a list of contacts based on their MIME type in Android.

For example I want a list of contacts which have email addresses.

Answer (score 2):

You should read a raw contact along with all the data associated with it by using the `ContactsContract.RawContacts.Entity` directory. If the raw contact has data rows, the entity cursor will contain a row for each data row. If the raw contact has no data rows, the cursor will still contain one row with the raw contact-level information.

```
Uri rawContactUri =
  ContentUris.withAppendedId(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, rawContactId);

Uri entityUri =
  Uri.withAppendedPath(rawContactUri, Entity.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);

Cursor c =
  getContentResolver().query(
    entityUri,
    new String[] {
      RawContacts.SOURCE_ID, Entity.DATA_ID, Entity.MIMETYPE, Entity.DATA1 },
    null, null, null);

try {
     while (c.moveToNext()) {
         String sourceId = c.getString(0);
         if (!c.isNull(1)) {
             String mimeType = c.getString(2);
             String data = c.getString(3);
             //decide here based on mimeType, see comment later
         }
     }
} finally {
     c.close();
}
```

For example, if the `mimeType` is `Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE`, then the column `DATA1` stores the phone number, but if the data kind is `Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE`, then `DATA1` stores the email address.

Answer (score 1):

To be generic and future-proof, you may want to use, for instance, [CommonDataKinds.Email](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.html), which provide constants for both the content types and the column names of the respective data, so you could write something like

```
String email = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Email.ADDRESS));
```

And you may, of course, provide a condition to [`ContentResolver.query()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#query%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String%29) to retrieve only the records of interest, using [MIMETYPE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.DataColumns.html#MIMETYPE) and other constants from `DataColumns`.