# List of Mimetypes supported by android contacts

Tags: android, database, android-contacts

I am preparing a contact app where i need to get the list of Mimetypes supported by android contacts.
For ex: Some devices support `SIP address` and some devices.
So i want to insert SIP address when it is supported then how can check that mimetype is supported.
I have found mimetypes table in contacts db of android in `com.android.providers.contacts` package.
How I will be able to access that mimetypes table in `contacts2.d`b database.

Please help.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942298/get-contacts-by-mime-type-in-android

Comment: Sorry but I don't want the contact associated with mimetype. I want the list of mimetypes supported by device @Abhi

Comment: It seems that the answer below is is not solving the problem , have you found a solution to your original problem i..e reading the mimetypes?

Comment: @Tito may be this is due to change in Android API's. Earlier it used to work I will change and update accordingly.

Comment: the question seems to ask a  list of Mimetypes i do not understand which variable hold that list

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check a mimetype is supported by a device - here is what you would do

```
Uri entityUri =
  Uri.withAppendedPath(
         ContentUris.withAppendedId(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, rawContactId), Entity.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);

Cursor c =
  getContentResolver().query(
    entityUri,
    new String[] {
      RawContacts.SOURCE_ID, Entity.DATA_ID, Entity.MIMETYPE, Entity.DATA1 },
    null, null, null);

try {
     while (c.moveToNext()) {
         String sourceId = c.getString(0);
         if (!c.isNull(1)) {
             String mimeType = c.getString(2);
             String data = c.getString(3);
                PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
                Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                testIntent.setType(mimeType );
                if (packageManager.queryIntentActivities(testIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY).size() > 0) {
                      // do something - it is supported
                  } else {
                  return false;
                }
         }
     }
} finally {
     c.close();
}
```

Comment: But I dont have any of the contacts previously stored soo how can i add rawContactId.

Comment: So you do not have the contacts, but you want to find out the MiMETypes supported by the Android Contacts?

Comment: Access the contact db? I am confused. Whereas if you have list of MimeTypes and you want to know if there is an handler  `PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
                Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                testIntent.setType(mimeType );
                if (packageManager.queryIntentActivities(testIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY).size() > 0) {
                      // do something - it is supported
                  } else {
                  return false;
                }`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. But as i don't have any mimetypes stored I want to retrieve it from Mimetypes table of contacts db. How can I do that?

Comment: Use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562151/android-get-all-contacts to list all the contacts - and for each contact find out the associated MimeType as in `String mimeType = c.getString(2)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74601/discussion-between-abhi-and-zeus).