# Android contacts2.db read mimetypes column (not records in the data table)

Tags: android, android-contacts

Android contacts `database` has a column called `mimetypes`. That is being created per default when the `database` is instantiated.

I have found one question that is trying to solve the exact same problem but there is no solution to the question although there is even an accepted answer.(on the below link)

[on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29474758/list-of-mimetypes-supported-by-android-contacts#)

```
"1" "vnd.android.cursor.item/email_v2"
"2" "vnd.android.cursor.item/im"
"3" "vnd.android.cursor.item/nickname"
"4" "vnd.android.cursor.item/organization"
"5" "vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2"
"6" "vnd.android.cursor.item/sip_address"
"7" "vnd.android.cursor.item/name"
"8" "vnd.android.cursor.item/postal-address_v2"
"9" "vnd.android.cursor.item/identity"
"10"    "vnd.android.cursor.item/photo"
"11"    "vnd.android.cursor.item/group_membership"
"12"    "vnd.android.cursor.item/note"
"13"    "vnd.android.cursor.item/contact_event"
"14"    "vnd.android.cursor.item/website"
"15"    "vnd.android.cursor.item/relation"
"16"    "vnd.com.google.cursor.item/contact_misc"
```

Now i would like to read this `column` trough context provider and get the id of each `mimetype` as an `integer` i.e. i am not interested in the string but in the id itself. I have not found any Context provider that gives me that possibility. Is there a way to do that. Ideal what i would like to receive is a `HashMap<Integer, String>` that represent that column.

Please note that i know how to get the `mimetype` of an `record` in the `data column` i.e.

```
String mimetype = cursorData.getString(cursorData.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE ));
```

This is not what i am looking for. I am looking for the `mimetypes` column.

Comment: Hello @pskink i want to  have  hashMap in the memory that i can query that gives me all possible combinations of mimetype + contentType of an record.  specific to the contacts database I.e. mimetype is the group and contentType is the exact type of that record. The reason for this is i want to be able to identify a record in the data column by just looking at those to values

Comment: exmaple of content type is ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE

Comment: My original goal is to read all contacts and classify their field , for example you have an android app that display the address book. If i display mobile number on my app i need to know that it is first  a phone number i.e. the mimetype and then i need to tell the app what exact button to display i.e. the type of the mobile number button.  now i need a structure (Hash Map) in the app that hold those possibility before the number is displayed since it is a web app.

Comment: hello @pskink yes that is correct i still would like to get the id of the mimetype. I have just compiled parts of the solution from the link you provided since i was hoping to find  a field  in the ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Contactables.CONTENT_URI;  that would allow me to do that but with no luck. I still do not understand how to get that list of mimetypes. In order to be clear, to me it is the list of the supported  mimetype what is important . Since that might change from version to version i.e. from phone to phone.

Comment: `...that hold those possibility before the number is displayed since it is a web app` the list of mimetypes is not stable, every app is free to add data to the contacts table with a new mimetype of their own, so if you're planning on having some fixed table on the server-side of ids, that won't help. just pass the string representation of the mimetype to be recognized as phone/email/etc by your app

Comment: youa re saying that i should manually create that list myself ?

Comment: well it will be good  if a query will be possible on the data table based on pre existing list of strings i.e. the query will display only the record that the aplication can deal with anyway. something like that.

Comment: if that's what you're after, you can query the db with a list of all known mimetypes, and create your own set of ids to each one of them. then you'll only get in return data from mimetypes that are (a) known to your app and (b) have an id

Comment: yup that will work for me. however i am still kind of surprised that there is no way of reading the mimetypes column from the db. I still do not understand why is that the case.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the discussion in the comments, there's no API to read the list of all mimetypes, as this is an internal table used by the Contacts DB, and isn't part of the external API requirements.

If needed to set some constant ID to each mimetype, a developer can create a static list of all known mimetypes available through the API (can be queried), and set their own IDs to each of those.
Since mimetypes can be added freely by app developers, this list will only support Android supplied mimetypes, and not custom ones.